# Closing DB Statement

Tags: java

```
 DBPreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try
    {
        stmt = new DBPreparedStatement(UTIL.getDatabase(), sql.toString(), "Graph.saveLastGraphName");
        stmt.setString(1, DBGlobals.doubleQuote(graphNameUsed));
        stmt.setString(2, userUpper);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DBGlobals.Error("OHMjson.Graph.saveLastGraphName - Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        msg = "Unable to save data";
        status = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stmt != null)
            stmt.close();
    }
```

I am closing the database statement inside the finally block, is it the right way. 
Will this cause any memory leakage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would agree with you that this is the right way to do it.  Closing it in the finally block will ensure that the statement is always closed, even in the exceptional case.  You could probably even get rid of the `stmt.close()` in your try, as it will get called in the finally block.

Comment: Emphasis on removing the `stmt.close()` statement from the `try` block. Otherwise it's called twice!